# How to find a mixed fit function for two histograms

Tags: c++, root-framework

I have two functions, a randomly generated Gaus and Land

```
TH1D *h1 = new TH1D("h1","", 100, 0,50);
TH1D *h2 = new TH1D("h2","", 100, 0,50);

for (Int_t i=0 i<10000; i++){
h1->Fill(r1->Landau(20,5));
h2->Fill(r1->Gaus(5,3));};


h1->Fit("landau");
h2->Fit("gaus");
```

So I am able to get individual fits, but I want to get a fit that combines BOTH the gaus and the land curves.

Thanks!

Comment: Totally unrelated: See if you can lose the pointers and dynamic allocation. `TH1D *h1 = new TH1D("h1","", 100, 0,50);` -> `TH1D h1("h1","", 100, 0,50);`  Fewer management headaches later and usually a bit faster.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You have two histograms, and you make two fits: the Landau histogram with a Landau function, and the Gauss histogram with a Gauss function. What do you mean by "get a fit that combines BOTH the gaus and the land curves"?

Comment: In addition to what @Keldorn said: you will probably add the two histograms together later on, won't you? And then you will want to fit the **resulting** gauss+Landau distribution... There is a good tutorial for exactly this case, see [here](https://root.cern/doc/master/langaus_8C.html).